# Concatenate the output of multiple cuts in one line in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, cut

I am trying to concatenate the output of three cut functions with `-`  in a shell script in a single line. I tried as below, but wont work. How do I do this ?

`echo "$(cut -d',' -f2 FILE.csv)-$(cut -d',' -f1 FILE.csv)-$(cut -d',' -f3 FILE.csv)"`

Comment: Please describe the problem better than "won't work". Give the exact input file, expected result and actual result.

Comment: If `FILE.csv` contains just one line, it should work. If it contains multiple lines and you want to merge the fields line by line, please try instead `paste -d'-' <(cut -d',' -f2 FILE.csv) <(cut -d',' -f1 FILE.csv) <(cut -d',' -f3 FILE.csv)` or `awk 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS="-"} {print $2,$1,$3}' FILE.csv`.

Comment: The output of each cut command will be that field from *every* line of the file. So you'll get all field 2, then all field 1, then all field 3.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` to change the delimiter:

```sh
awk -F, '{ print $2, $1, $3 }' OFS='-' FILE.csv
```

Or with [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) commands (Especially useful if your file has more complex CSV with things like commas in quoted fields or multi-line fields that a naive split on comma can't handle correctly):

```sh
csvcut --columns 2,1,3 FILE.csv | csvformat -D'-'
```